# La aplicación se crashea al utilizar Proguard - Chromecast V3

Tags: android

Necesito ayuda para mover mi aplicación a producción.
Cuando instalo el apk generado devuelve el siguiente error :

> "Unable to resume activity {[package] .MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException Error al inicializar CastContext"

Nota: Esto ocurre cuando habilito minifyEnabled a true, cuando está en false no hay problema.

[image: Adjunto foto de error log.]

Comment: Grover, escribe por favor tu pregunta en idioma español o será cerrada.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque está en inglés y debe ser traducida al español o migrada a SOen

Comment: Acabo de actualizar el contenido.

Comment: Aparece un problema con un ClassNotFoundException ¿si estas incluyendo la clase? y si la incluyes, ¿no tiene algún error? eso pasa seguido con proguard que borra las clases que piensa el que no se necesitan, por lo que en la configuración de tu proguard deberás añadir la excepción a esa clase.

Comment: Te faltó traducir el título.

Comment: Podrías revisar la siguiente página para la configuración de proguard y/o pasarnos lo que tu tienes de configuración.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830474/how-to-keep-exclude-a-particular-package-path-when-using-proguard

Comment: @Ajeno no la llamo en ningún momento asumo que es parte del uso de la misma librería del cast. 
En el proguard incluso estoy dandole el -dontwarn y -keep a toda la clase que contiene la configuracion de ChromeCast.
Lo tengo de la siguiente manera:
-keep class com.gtb.tvperuana.util.ChromeCastUtils { *; }
-keep public class com.gtb.tvperuana.util.ChromeCastUtils.*
-dontwarn com.gtb.tvperuana.util.ChromeCastUtils

Comment: Esta clase no es creada por ti entonces? com.gtb.tvperuana.CastOptionsProvider

Comment: Agregale esta -keep  class com.gtb.tvperuana.CastOptionsProvider {;}

Comment: @Ajeno gracias, ya lo solucioné con lo que me indicaste. Saludos.

Comment: @Ajeno deberías agregar una respuesta explicando que realiza lo que indicas dentro del .proguard

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de solucionar el problema de la siguiente manera.

```
-keep class [Package].CastOptionsProvider { *; }
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: y esto que realiza en tu proyecto?